# Kafka Message reach consumer with atleast 200ms delay

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using Spring Kafka.When I post a single message to kafka topic I can see that it is consumed by the consumer with atleast 200ms delay.

I am using default producer properties .Below is my consumer properties.
Consumer properties:

request timeout ms 30 seconds

heartbeat interval ms 3 seconds

max poll interval ms 5 minutes

max poll records 200

session timeout ms 45 seconds

I tried changing the properties of consumer like max.poll.interval.ms and max.poll.recors but nothing helped.Below is consumer code.

```
@KafkaListener(groupid = AlertsKafkaConfig.GROUP_ID_JSON, topics = TopicNameConstants.Webhook_doc_process_topic_name, containerFacotry = KafkaTopicConstans.WEBHOOK_PROCESS_TOPIC_CONF)
Public void receiveProcessPricessingMessage(@Payload String kafkajsonstring, @Header(KafkaHeaders RECEIVED_TIMESTAMP) String timestamp, @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) String offset) throws JsonProcessingException {

    try {

        WebhookProcessingCommand eventprocessingcommand = gson.fromJson(kafkajsonstring, WebhookProcessingCommand.class);

        eventprocessinghandler.processEvent(eventprocessingcommand);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        LOGGER.error(ExceptionUtils.fullStackTrace(e));

    }

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What kind of a delay did you expect? 200ms is not surprising - the message has to go over the network, get replicated to other broker nodes and then go over the network again.

Comment: @GaryRussell  Actually our requirement is to process each message within 100 ms.Our processing is done within 50 ms but the time taken to reach the message once it gets posted by kafka producer to the topic to reach our consumer is 200ms.So total time of execution is 250ms.

Comment: As I said, 200ms is not surprising; your requirements seem to be too intense for this technology.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell understood.this was the answer I was expecting if it is possible using kafka or not